# Need Date Picker in Excel sheet column to choose dates

Tags: javascript, reactjs, excel

I Need to date picker in excel sheet to upload the bulk upload product in the list to choose stock date i need that,I have a React Excel upload there i could not upload a date picker in that i could not able to show the date picker asi need of that so that i could be able to chode date like caleder format.

Comment: Have you read this? 

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel/excel-date-picker/m-p/1687033

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.